# What is the difference between 完成 and 完毕?

Tags: word-choice

So, both mean 'to finish, complete sth.'. I guess 完毕 is more formal, because the examples given for it include things like court cases, whereas 完成 seems to be things like homework/general tasks.
Any other differences between the two?!
Regards,
A very thankful Hashamyim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

完成 mainly mean '**accomplish**' ('成' in '完成' means successfully or become) ; 完成 is mostly for 'something people do'

完毕 mainly mean '**end**' ('毕' in '完毕' means 'end'); 完毕 is mostly for 'something that happens'

*完毕 syn 完結 (ended)*

> 完成 (v) to complete; **to accomplish**; to fulfill; to **finish**; to succeed
>
> 完成 can be used with or without object
>
> E.g. 已经完成工作 and 工作已经完成 are both correct

~

> 完毕 (v) **to end**; to finish; to complete
>
> 完毕 doesn't take object
>
> E.g. 學期完毕; 工作完毕 (you can't say 完毕學期 or 完毕工作) (學期  and  工作 are both subject in the phrase )

- When you want to say an event is 'ended', you have to use 完毕
- When you want to say a task is 'accomplished', you have to use 完成
- Do not use 完成 for 'an event is ended' (學期完成 is incorrect, )

Answer (score 2):

```
完毕 - Finish  
完成 - Complete
```

They're slightly different even in English.  See [What is the difference between 'finished' and 'completed'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/54858/what-is-the-difference-between-finished-and-completed)

Comment: Well, that's weird - I'm a native English speaker yet I had never given much thought to the difference between finish and complete. How interesting and makes a lot of sense! I finished my stamp collection vs. I completed my stamp collection. Well, you live and learn lol

Comment: @Hashamyim haha yes, my friend always joke about how much different it is between couples - "We're finished" vs "We're completed"

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers are helpful.

Actually we don’t often use 完毕. You can use 完成 in all situations. XD

Comment: all situations？(although 完毕 has 10 times the frequency #of  完成 (see comment 1) (indicating relatively low usage frequency)，there are well established speech formulas requiring 完毕, see comment 2, and note that it corresponds to "10-4" or "over" when ending any kind of speech transmission between professionals (truckers, police).iciba:1.

Alpha-Bravo-Zulu 643 to Saltezar, do you read me? Over.

阿尔法－布拉沃－祖鲁643呼叫萨德扎，能听到我的声音吗？完毕。 We read you loud and clear. Over.

我们能够清楚地听到你的声音。完毕。

Comment: My feeling is that it’s more formal to use 完毕, which puts more emphasis on the completion of one thing. 完成 is most widely used, while only in a report we use 完毕 at the end of the sentence. Take it easy, we can understand it whatever you use.

Answer (score 0):

完毕 does not exactly mean complete. It means the end of a process or a task. 
完成 Means complete

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically, 完毕 is often used as a **complement**. 完成 can be used as **an transitive verb or a noun**.

For example, we say 准备完毕， 准备 is a verb and 完毕 is its result complement. When we say 准备完成, we use 完成as an transitive verb, so we should add an object like 准备完成这项工作. 完成 sometimes can be used as a noun word, like 这项工作的完成. We don't usually say 这项工作的完毕. That is to say, 完毕 is not used as a noun normally.